# Python crashes when assert fails

Tags: python, pytest, playwright

I'm trying to use Playwright and pytest to test my website. My code keeps crashing when it fails. Below I've explained the things I've tried and why it keeps crashing. I could hack out a solution that wouldn't crash (initialise `test` first), but it's sloppy and I know there's a much better way to do it.

My question: When an org is successfully created, a popup appears saying 'Organisation has been updated'. How can I do an assertion that this element has appeared, without crashing if it doesn't? Thank you.

My first attempt. This crashes because `page.locator` couldn't find the element it was expecting.

```
test = page.locator("text=Organisation has been updated").inner_html()
assert test != ''
```

My second attempt. This crashes as `test` is undefined

```
try:
    test = page.locator("text=Organisation has been updated").inner_html()
except:
    pass
assert test != ''
```

edit - added my pytest code

```
import pytest
import pyotp

#Super admin can add, edit and delete an organisation
def test_super_admin_add_organisation(page):
    page.goto("https://website/login/")
    page.locator("[aria-label=\"Email\"]").click()
    [...]
    page.wait_for_url("https://website.com.au/two-factor-verification/")

    # Two-Factor Authentication
    totp = pyotp.TOTP("otp")
    page.locator("[aria-label=\"Two Factor Pin\"]").fill(totp.now()) 
    with page.expect_navigation():
        page.click('button:has-text("Verify")')

    page.wait_for_url("https://website.com.au/organisations/")
    page.locator("button:has-text(\"add\")").click()
    page.locator("[aria-label=\"Organisation\"]").click()
    page.locator("[aria-label=\"Organisation\"]").fill("test_org")
    [...]
    page.locator("button:has-text(\"save\")").click()

    try:
        org_added = ''
        org_added = page.locator("text=Organisation has been updated. close").inner_html()
    except:
        pass
    assert org_added != ''
```

Comment: A "crash" is just an unhandled exception that causes the program to stop.  You used an `assert` that will raise an `AssertionError` if `test` is empty; usually the reason you use `assert` is that the condition should never be true, and so if it is, you want the program to stop immediately so you can debug it instead of letting it continue.  In this case it turns out that `test` is indeed empty, so the program stops, *exactly like you told it to in this situation*.  **What do you want your code to do instead of stopping?**

Comment: Set `test = ''` before the `try`?

Comment: Do you just want an `if` statement?

Comment: @Samwise I'd like my code just to continue to the next test, with the failed test being marked as failed through pytest

Comment: By "next test" you mean the next test *function*, right?  Because that is indeed what pytest does, but it won't continue running a test that has already failed (i.e. by raising an exception).  Each function you run via pytest should therefore test one thing.

Comment: @Samwise Yes, this is what I mean. To move on to the next test function

Comment: @Grismar , Kraigolas. I can definitely do either, though I thought either wouldn't be a good approach. But I guess they're fine. In which case, easy. Thank you

Comment: @horse You should include the pytest output in your question, and maybe a sample of your test file with a couple of test functions.  I suspect there's some confusion going on about how to actually run pytest and seeing your output might clear it up.

Comment: @Samwise . Okay, I added my test code. Thanks a lot.

Comment: How are you actually running this code?  **Where is the output?**  The fact that your test function takes a `page` argument makes me think you aren't actually running it through `pytest` (which will mark a test as failed if it raises an exception, but won't generally "crash" the whole test suite).  I asked to see the output earlier because I want to see if it looks like pytest output and/or has any more useful error information than "it keeps crashing".